# Prohibit users from choosing a specified username

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making a Laravel application and my users are able to choose their `username` while registering but I also want to prohibit them from choosing some user names such as "Admin, Administrator, etc." how can I do that?

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a custom validation for it .. in your AppServiceProvider

```
public function boot() 
{ 
    Validator::extend('not_exist', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters,$validator) 
    { 
        if(count(Prohibit::where('name','=',$value)->get()) == 0){ 
            return true; 
        } 
        return false; 
    }); 
}
```

then in resources/lang/en/validation.php add this to the array

```
'not_exist' => ":attribute prohibitted.",
```

Comment: need these also `use Validator;` `use App\Probihit;` and in register form validation `'username' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users|not_exist',`

Comment: @robertnicjoo if you want to go with DB solution, just use `unique` rule (check my answer), you don't need to create a custom rule for that.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I found it i actually need because `unique:table_name,name` method wouldn't work perfectly it actually allows usernames in that table to be register which i want to avoid that, secondly it has issue with lowercase & capitalcase so admin must add both with that method, etc.  so I prefer this solution would work the best depend on my needs.

Comment: try > 0 not == 0

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`not_in`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-not-in) validation rule:

```
'name' => 'not_in:Admin,Administrator'
```

Or you can keep the list of words in DB table and use [`unique`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-unique) rule:

```
'name' => 'unique:table_name,name'
```

It's a better choice if you want to allow admin to edit these words.

Comment: how to make it not to be case sensitive?

Comment: @robertnicjoo in this case you can [create your own validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-validation-rules) and use `in_array()` function to check if a string value is one of the words in an array.

Comment: this will not do .. exists works if it exists and gives an error if not ..

Answer (score 0):

Add a validation rule `not_in:admin,Administrator,...`

Comment: how to make it not to be case sensitive?